# SQL Query, Create new column instead a new row SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

i try create a query to get all products and your repectives dates and packs:

```
SELECT 
p.id,
d.date,
pc.pack
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN Dates d ON p.id = d.id
LEFT JOIN Packs pc ON p.id = pc.id;
```

[image: Products Table]
[image: Dates Table]
[image: Packs Table]

Result:

[image: Result]

But i need the query return a table like this:

[image: Ex 1]

Or this:

[image: Ex 2]

Tks for attention =]]]]]]]]

EDIT:

```
ID  PRODUCT
1   AAA
2   BBB
3   CCC
4   DDD

ID  DATE
1   2022-05-01
1   2023-02-08
2   2021-10-25
3   2020-04-18
3   2021-06-07
3   2023-01-19
4   2022-12-21

ID  PACK
1   4
2   6
2   12
3   8
3   16
4   1
4   10
4   20
```

Comment: Can you share your data as code instead of images

Comment: I added tables like code, =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `LISTAGG` `DISTINCT` can do the trick.

The [LISTAGG](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HT1O85E4BHSBWN93G1B3M8SI2.html) aggregate function supports duplicate elimination by using the new DISTINCT.

Since you dont want duplicated packs/dates this is how to do it :

```
with cte as (
  SELECT p.id, d.date_, pc.pack
  FROM products p
  LEFT JOIN dates d ON p.id = d.id
  LEFT JOIN packs pc ON p.id = pc.id
)
select id,
  listagg (DISTINCT date_,', ' on overflow truncate with count) 
  within group (order by date_) dates,
  listagg (DISTINCT pack,', ' on overflow truncate with count) 
  within group (order by pack) packs
from cte
group by id;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/WgmYz6eC)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use STRING_AGG?

```
SELECT p.id, LISTAGG(d.date, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(
ORDER BY
    d.date
) AS dates, LISTAGG(pc.pack, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(
ORDER BY
    pc.pack
) AS packs
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN Dates d ON p.id = d.id
LEFT JOIN Packs pc ON p.id = pc.id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Comment: ORA-00904: "STRING_AGG": invalid identifier, But LISTAGG works fine